# insert a new row using decoded json string

Tags: php, mysql, json

`$str` is a json object-string from client side
`keys` are column names
need to insert a new row using prepared values - i.e. corresponding key value pairs
how can I do - like this:

```
$str = {"fname":"lorem","sname":"ipsum","nick":"dolor"};

function btn_send($str){
    global $db;
    $obj = json_decode($str);
    $sq = "insert into members (...keys) values (...prepared_values)";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute([...]);
}
```

Comment: Look into ORMs there's no way to do this with the pdo or mysqli libraries.

Comment: @nice_dev - that is `$str`

Comment: @qadenza Ahh, overlooked that. So, keys in that json are column names for the table?

Comment: @nice_dev - yes, that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


$str = '{"fname":"lorem","sname":"ipsum","nick":"dolor"}';

function btn_send($str){
    global $db;
    $data = json_decode($str,true);
    $column_names = "`". implode("`,`",array_keys($data)) . "`";
    $prepared_chars = implode(",",array_fill(0,count(array_values($data)),'?'));
    $sq = "insert into members ($column_names) values ($prepared_chars)";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute(array_values($data));
}
```

You can make the column names out of the json keys and have those many `?` placeholders as much as values for those keys. While executing the prepared query, you can just supply the values.

Comment: getting syntax error on `$st = $db->prepare($sq);` - probably one line before

Comment: @qadenza Ok, what does $sq show on echoing?

Comment: @qadenza Fixed it now. I missed a comma.

Comment: works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Seems php needs a native function for this

Comment: @qadenza True, PHP needs to provide this apparently.